# SQL like statement excluding Strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find all address that have a P.O. Box.  However, my problem is the letters PO could be part of the street name and the query is return incomplete results.

Here's what I have tried...

```
where       (a.address like '%p.o.%'
or          a.address like '%po %'
or          a.address like '% po%'
or          a.address like '% po %'
or          a.address like '%[^A-Za-z]PO[^A-Za-z]%'
or          a.address like '%[^A-Za-z]P.O[^A-Za-z]%'
or          a.address like '%[^A-Za-z]P.O.[^A-Za-z]%')
```

With the above code I'm still getting street names like POLK and POINT and PORTLAND..and others.  How do I exclude anything that has letters before or after PO and only return the letters I'm looking for?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE 
(
    a.address like '%PO%'
    OR a.address like '%P.O%'
    OR a.address like '%P.O.%'
)
AND a.address NOT like '%[A-Z]PO%'
AND a.address NOT like '%PO[A-Z]%'
AND a.address NOT like '%[A-Z]P.O%'
AND a.address NOT like '%P.O[A-Z]%'
AND a.address NOT like '%[A-Z]P.O.%'
AND a.address NOT like '%P.O.[A-Z]%'
```

I've removed the lower letters variants but they are only needed if you are using a case sensitive collation for addresses

Answer (score 1):

```
where       ' ' + lower(a.address) + ' ' like '%[^a-z]po[^a-z]%'
        or  ' ' + lower(a.address) + ' ' like '%[^a-z]p.o[^a-z]%'
```

Comment: It will be really helpful for question and for StackOverflow community if you add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The way ive always done it was by using something that would look like this

```
CHECK (a.adress_like( foo, '[POpo]' ) )
```

or

```
select * from table where Name like '%POpo%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should likely be good enough

```
WHERE REPLACE(address,'.','') LIKE '%po%' 
  AND REPLACE(address,'.','') NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]po[A-Z]%'
```

Unless you are on a case sensitive collation no need to bother with the `a-z`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz The question says "How do I exclude anything that has letters before or after PO" it doesn't say they have to be immediately before or after.